# How to use MySQL for .NET Core Azure functions

Tags: mysql, function, azure

I am attempting to write an Azure function and use MySQL but I cannot seem to use the MySQL.Data or MySql.Data.MySqlClient directives. The error I am getting is the following:

```
The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found.
```

I am not sure what I need to make this work

```
using MySql.Data; 
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Comment: I assume you tried to create the Function from within the Azure portal? Getting external package references right this way is tricky. I'd recommend to create your function for example using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be either Nuget/Project type issue. Try the following,

1. use NuGet to download the latest version. Just right click on the project and click 'Manage NuGet Packages' then search online for MySql.Data and install.

Check the project or create a new project

2. To change your project's framework right-click on your project select Properties -> Application -> Target framework.